# What is wrong with this SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The SQL is:

```
execute ('delete from HttpRequests where Date < ''2009-08-' + convert(nvarchar(max), 0) + '''')
```

The error is

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.
```

Commenting out the convert part removes the error. Whats wrong?

Comment: I'd vote for 3 quotes at the end rather than 4.

Comment: By the way, you do know it's possible to build a predicate string without needing to use dynamic SQL, right?  Generally speaking, you should treat `execute` in SQL like `eval()` in dynamic languages: a very powerful, very dangerous tool that should only be used when nothing else will do.

Comment: You know, I cannot imagine what you are trying to do here that isn't better and more safely done with normal date handling functions.  Actually, I can't image what you are trying to do by using these constructs, period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXECUTE (@stringvariable)` does not allow concatenation more complex than `@stringvariable1 + @stringvariable2`

You'd have to do this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = 'delete from HttpRequests where Date < ''2009-08-' + convert(nvarchar(4000), 0) + '''
EXECUTE (@sql)
```

However, then you have the invalid date error... and I've fixed the quote error too...

Answer (score 12):

Replace "execute" with "print", drop the parenthesis, and run, and you get

```
delete from HttpRequests where Date < '2009-08-0'
```

That is not a valid date.

Comment: When syntax errors are involved, the actual errors thrown by SQL tend to be somewhat... arbitrary.

Comment: No, the problem is that you can't perform operations like that within EXEC (just like you can't call EXEC dbo.someProc @foo = (@bar + 1);).  Use a variable as a placeholder once you get proper date formatting in place, then use EXEC(@variable);.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the statement.  SQL simply doesn't allow passing result of CONVERT expression to EXEC.  I can't find any documentation for this, but many people report this behavior.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34917755/pass-result-of-convert-as.aspx

Comment: `execute` does not create a stored procedure, so your comment does not apply.  Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I know that.  My point was regarding passing parameters to EXEC.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be creating a valid date.

```
select 'delete from HttpRequests where Date < ''2009-08-' + convert(nvarchar(max), 0)
```

+ ''''

would give you: delete from HttpRequests where Date < '2009-08-0'

Answer (score -2):

Query dates like yyyyMMdd and put max between [].

Comment: SQL Server can understand dates in ISO 8601 format ("yyyy-MM-dd") and `nvarchar(max)` is legal syntax for SQL Server.

Comment: That can be, but is it clear what is meant? Max can misinterpreted as a reserved word. Date like yyyyMMdd is more used than dates containing '-' or '/'. I really wouldn't want to read your code Daniel, even when it works..

Comment: Daniel, YYYYMMDD is much safer.  Try this:  SET LANGUAGE FRENCH; SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2009-11-13');

Comment: I'm sorry, are you saying that ISO 8601 is ambiguous?  It's an international standard, after all.  The YYYYMMDD form is called *basic format* by the standard, while the YYYY-MM-DD form is called *extended format*.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates .  I wasn't trying to say that YYYYMMDD is a bad idea (I think it's a great idea, by the way), but that YYYY-MM-DD *ought* to work, and thus isn't the problem here.

Comment: @Michel: You say: "Max can be misinterpreted as a reserved word."  This is true.  But the syntax `nvarchar(max)` is well documented, and there is no alternative syntax for specifying that you want a string with up to 2^31-1 bytes of storage (if you specify a numeric value, the maximum is 4000 bytes).  So there is nothing wrong with using `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: Daniel, I'm not suggesting that YYYY-MM-DD is the problem here.  I'm suggesting that in general it is not a good choice in SQL Server because it CAN be a problem in other instances.  Did you try the sample I posted?